# Why the "while" loop works but the "for" one doesn't?

Tags: python, function, reverse

I've just started learning python.
I'm trying to make a reverse function for strings, and I know this code works:

```
def reverse(text):
    string_list = list(text)
    new_list = []
    length = len(string_list) - 1
    while length >= 0:
        new_list.append(string_list[length])
        length = length - 1
    return ''.join(new_list)
```

but I don't understand why this one doesn't:

```
def reverse(text):
    string_list = list(text)
    new_list = []
    for i in len(text)-1:
        new_list.append(string_list[len(text)-i])
    return "".join(new_list)
```

How to make the for loop work? Where's the error?

Comment: reverse is sort of a keyword ... I would name your function something else ...

Comment: `"ASD"[::-1]` is a better way to reverse it or `"".join(reversed("ASD"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `range` or better `xrange`:

```
for i in xrange(len(text)):
    new_list.append(string_list[len(text) - 1 - i])
```

Comment: where did you know that is the issue he got?

Comment: Because he also forgot to subtract 1 from the length.

Comment: @Cyber This time, it was my bad :) Sorry that I don't have a chance to test. I've updated my answer.

Comment: There you go, 3rd time's a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def reverse(text):
    string_list = list(text)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        new_list.append(string_list[len(text) -1- i])
    return "".join(new_list)
```

> reverse('joe') => 'eoj'

With this code you will neither have a `list index out of range` error nor miss a character from your string.

Answer (score 0):

Start from index 1 and use range()

```
for i in range(1,len(text)+1):
```

Comment: @ozgur He has used `new_list.append(string_list[len(text)-i])` so the loop would go from 1 to len(text) rather than 0 to len(text)-1 [both inclusive].

Answer (score 0):

Got the error, use this in corresponding line

```
for i in range(len(text))
```

and

```
new_list.append(string_list[(len(text)-1)-i])
```